# how to add method description for visual studio code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

On some methods, Visual Studio Code ( VSC ) automatically describes the intellisense suggestions like this :

[image]

How can this be done for custom code, I tried finding out on the source for this name interface:
and found this piece of code :

```
    /** Returns a string representation of a function. */
toString(): string;
```

So I tried adding the same to my class method:

```
      /** Returns a string representation of a function. */
nowUTS()
      {

        return Math.round(Date.now()/1000);
      }
```

But when VSC gives this method as a suggestion, I only get this visually:

[image]

How should I document my class methods for visual studio code intellisense to pick up the description ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place the documentation comment above the function `nowUTS()`. For reference check **JSDoc** documentation: https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html

Comment: Yes! Just edited my question to give another example and found this one out, always when I asking that the solutions pops out.. thank you

Answer (score 4):

You should install `jsdoc` add in

[image]

Link download https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevencl.addDocComments

More at https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_jsdoc-support

Answer (score 0):

JSDoc is not required since VS Code can interpret most of the JSDoc syntax. The unit that contains the JSDoc comments has to be saved before the comments appear in other units in the editor.

Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_jsdoc-support